# Unable to access OAuth 2.0 access token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I m new in using spring security. What I am trying to do is :1
1. I have an Identity micro-service running on a different port
2. and a portal service running on a different port.

The identity service is responsible for user authentication. The user has {username, password, Set, organization-info}.

The portal service uses this identity service to authenticate its users. 
I am using a `JwtAccessTokenConverter`  and a `TokenEnhancer` in my `SecurityConfiguration` of Identity application. The enhancer puts the additional information (eg the user's organization info) in the Oauth2AccessToken.

Now from the portal service I want to access this additional Information.

How can I access this additional information from the portal microservice.
I have tried the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` but its not helping.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` to implement an Oauth2 resource server.

Check the following dev guide for more information..
http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html